# Elemento Scroll da classe DataGrid WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, rolamento, datagrid

Tenho uma função que cria um grid,e precisava saber o valor do scroll desse grid, para poder disparar um evento quando chegasse no fim da página. Mas não sei como conseguir esses valor, a função está aqui em baixo:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

     public override FrameworkElement criar()
        {
          if (formulario == null)
            return null;

          DataGrid    grid = new DataGrid();
          ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();


          definirStyle(grid, "tema.estiloGradeDados");
          definirBinding(grid, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, "dados", true);

          grid.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
          grid.VerticalScrollBarVisibility   = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;

          grid.GroupStyle.Add(new GroupStyle() {ContainerStyleSelector = new SeletorEstiloItemGrupo() });
          grid.ContextMenu = menu;

          grid.Height = 800;

          foreach (DskCampo campo in dskFormulario.campos)
          {
            criarItemMenu(menu, campo);
            criarColuna  (grid, campo);
          }

          return grid;
        }
```

O scroll do DataGrid descende de "ScrollViewer" não? como faço para manipula-lo?

Comment: O `DataGrid` tem um evento `Scroll`, ele não ajuda?
[system.windows.forms.datagrid.scroll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.scroll(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Não, essa bibilioteca usa o forms, e eu estou usando o DataGrid do "System.Windows.Controls" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

O DataGrid tem uma propriedade chamada ScrollViewer, nele você pode adicionar o evento de scroll (ScrollChanged) e tem várias propriedades: ContentVerticalOffset, e várias outras relacionadas ao tamanho e scroll vertical.

Fonte: [ScrollViewer.ContentVerticalOffsetProperty Field](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.contentverticaloffsetproperty?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: A minha questão é exatamente como pegar essa propriedade então, dada a minha função acima. Não acho nenhum exemplo sobre como fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

No seu evento `ScrollChanged`, você pode usar o código abaixo:

```
int AlturaTotal = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows){
    AlturaTotal += row.Height;
}

if (AlturaTotal - grid.Height < grid.VerticalScrollingOffset)
{
    //quando entrar aqui é por que chegou na ultima linha
}
```

Comment: Estou usando o DataGrid do controls e não do forms, essas propriedades não existem no System.Windows.Controls;